# I need help changing a divs background image using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
#divbox{
  width:90%;
  height:60px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 0 auto;     
}

<div id="divbox" style="background-image: url('../home/images/sydney333x60.jpg');";>
```

and I want to change the image with jquery.

```
function callonbuttonclick(){
    $("#divbox").attr("src", "new image path");
}
```

but I am unable to find what I should use for '.attr' and/or "src".

I looked at some of the answers in stackoverflow but could not get them to work, I overlay the image with radio buttons but the example did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using "attr" is when you want to change a named attribute such as:

- checked="checked"
- src="someimage.jpg"
- width="100%"

Whereas, css handles anything inside the style attribute. You *could* use attr for style, but, you would be modifying the entire attribute instead of just the one property that you are interested in.

So,

```
$("#divbox").attr("src", "new image path");
```

would be for the src in

```
<img src="" />
```

Instead, use:

```
$("#divbox").css("background-image", "url('../path/to/new/image.jpg')");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, not just for the code but for the explanation as well.